# Continuous Time Markov Chain - M/M/2 Queue throughput

Tags: markov-process, continuous-time

First I find the stationary distribution of this problem by solving $\pi G=0$ to get $\pi \approx (0.20675105, 0.29535865, 0.05907173, 0.23628692, 0.1350211,  0.06751055)$. Using $\pi$, we can calculate the throughput of the system as $\sum_{i \in S} i\pi_i$ where $S = \{0,1M,1J,2,3,4\}$ and we simply let $1J=1M=1$. Therefore, we get $\sum_{i \in S} i\pi_i = 1.503$, which is greater than the arrival rate $\lambda = 1$. Isn't this erroneous?

Comment: Your blackboard seems to have $0,1J,1M,2,3,4$ rather than $0,1M,1J,2,3,4$ but this does not affect your question

Comment: @Henry Does the transition rate diagram appear to be accurate as well?

Comment: I can reproduce your $\pi$ myself but with an extra calculation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your stationary distribution looks sensible, though I think you may have done more than find $\pi$ such that $\pi J=\pi$ or $\pi G=0$:  I think you have also adjusted for the expected times in each state of $(1, \frac23, \frac12, \frac25, \frac4{11}, \frac12)$

I think you should then be multiplying $(0.20675105,0.29535865,0.05907173,0.23628692,0.1350211,0.06751055)$ by the rates of service in each state, i.e. by $(0,\frac12 ,1,\frac32,\frac32,\frac32)^T$, to get about $0.8649789$.  This is less than $\lambda=1$ so plausible on that criterion